# Prove that there are infinitely many pairs of distinct positive integers $x,y$ such that $x^2+y^3$ is divisible by $x^3+y^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Tried many approaches without any luck. Couldn't find 1 pair even by plugging in random values. Help.

Comment: Kindly present at least one approach, out of the many you tried, that did not work, and let's try to see why it didn't work.

Comment: Obviously $(x,y)=(2,6)$ works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $y=kx$. It reduces to

$$(x+k^2)|(1+xk^3).$$

Then use that $x\equiv -k^2 \bmod (x+k^2)$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Excellent. Thanks a lot.